Does Chrome sync website cookies and cache across devices when sync is turned on?
Does Chrome sync website cookies and cache across devices when sync is turned on? And also will these cookies and cache (images, videos, script files) sync if you mess up any settings or dev tool or anything on the browser?
Let's say I opened a website that contains cookies or cache such as images, videos and files and all the types of them on device A but I don't open the website on device B. Will these cache and cookies be downloaded or synced on device B or load on device B SSD or storage component or just generally be on device B ready to load?
And are cookies and cache saved on your email so if you add it on a device it's ready to load if the sync is turned on?

No, Google Chrome doesn't sync cookies or cache, for good reasons.
Syncing cookies would be a huge security flaw a lot of times. Imagine logging in in e.g. a library and accidentally leaving your bank or other important login data there. You don't really want that in any sort of a cloud either, you only open yourself to attacks. Of course you could be talking about some specific use case where only specific non-important websites are visited, but that's niche.
Syncing cache, on the other hand, is useless in many cases due to how much storage is potentially used for that and how low the percentage of repeats would be on other devices. The only reason I see for syncing it would be to preserve omnibox input. Otherwise it doesn't really matter if you download videos, images, scripts, etc. from the cloud or straight from the website again - you have to download it once anyways. The entire purpose of cache is to be volatile.
Consider alternatives for those:

for the most useful cookies you could very quickly log in to websites with a good password manager, on any sort of a device
for websites you visit very often, you could keep a list of links and then use addon like Open Multiple URLs to load them on a new device all at once, caching lots of their parts

